# Netbeans does not open on MacOS Big Sur. It's not able to find a java path or jdk not found

Tags: java, netbeans, java-home, macos-big-sur

After I upgraded Mac OS Big sur, Netbeans can not open on my Mac. I click Netbeans and nothing happened. I try to fix this problem, but I failed. Now can someone help me to resolve it?

It's have issue with java path. i setup path for the java_home but it's still not working.

I uninstall and install JAVA and netbeans both but it's still not working.

Comment: Have you found any solution?.. I am facing same problem.